# Running Esper in ARM Cortex-M4

Tags: microcontroller, cortex-m, esper, nesper

Is it possible to run Esper CEP in an LPC4088 microcontroller with a 120 MHz ARM Cortex-M4 core?

I wonder if it is possible to it under JVM or using Nesper for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Esper needs a 1.8 or higher JVM. As long as that hardware can run a JVM you should be ok. Nesper needs a certain minimum .NET CLR, same there.